# jQuery to replace one href value with another from children elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to work with how our system spits out its code for a calendar and due to the formatting, I need to change the href value of some links to the value of what its children link to. Below is some sample code:

```
<td class="date eventDate">
<a class="dateLink" href="calendar?DATE=2012-07-06&VIEW=day">6</a>
<br>
  <div>
    <div class="event">
      <a href="/calendar?date=20120702" class="event"></a>
      <a href="/calendar?root=320794" class="eventon">6 July</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

I need jQuery to replace the href value of the first  tag with the href value of the third  tag. I'm not really sure how I can get jQuery to look through all of the page's elements to achieve this.

I think the process is look for all a.dateLink and replace the current selection with the href value of the child element a.eventon, then move on to the next a.dateLink and repeat. If there is not child element a.eventon the move on to the next.

Can anyone help me with what I need?

Comment: How do you know it should be `/calendar?root=320794` rather than `/calendar?date=20120702`? Should the `href` of the first `<a>` in the table cell always be replaced with the `href` of the last `<a>`?

Comment: which of the two do you want to get, <a href="/calendar?date=20120702" class="event"></a> or this one 
      <a href="/calendar?root=320794" class="eventon">6 July</a>

Comment: @muistooshort /calendar?root=320794 is what I have set so that it works for what the client requires.

Comment: @JeffRobertDagala I always want to get the value of a.eventon to replace the value of a.dateLink
Hope that helps a bit

Comment: check my updated answer. :)
let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do

```
    $("td.data.eventDate").each(function(){
        if($(this).find("a.eventon") > 0)
        {
            $(this).children("a.dateLink").attr("href",$(this).children("a.eventon").attr("href"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - seeing the code made all the difference from theory to practice. Much appreciated

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 4):

here's some pseudocode to get you started:

```
//get all td.date.eventDate
//for each element in collection
    //find a.dateLink child
    //find a.eventon child
    //if a.eventon is not null or empty
        //set a.dateLink[href] to a.eventon[href]
    //else
        //continue loop
```

Comment: Excellent, so my thoughts were on the right path. I'll keep trying to see where I get. Thanks